# how to set selected value in v-select when first created

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-select

[foucs on first selected value](https://codepen.io/haji8-acloset/pen/RwLpwNg)

```
<v-select 
        v-model="select_value"
        :options="options"
        :reduce="val => val.id" 
        label="title"
        item-text="id">
```

I did set default v-select, but that component has many options with scoll.

When I open v-select, I want it to have focus to the default value.

but it doesn't work like select component.

is it v-select bug?

Comment: It seems like you're using the "vue-select" package and not Vuetify's "v-select" element. I think the prop `item-text` is for Vuetify and `reduce` is in vue-select do the same thing but they are from different libraries, so you can't use them on the same element.

Comment: Honestly the highlight selection feature is not consistent and IMO not worth hacking. If you use v-select to change the input, then the highlight is visible when you open the dropdown again. But if you hover over another option and close the dropdown, when you reopen it the last hovered item is highlighted instead of the option selected.

Comment: @Muge i wonder, before select focus on default value

Comment: i used vue-select package, it call shot name v-select